# Svg clipPath location

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

For the following image, I am trying to clip out everything that not located in the black box shown.

[image: Non clipped svg]

But I perform the clipPath operation and feMorphology filter to show where the clipped box is being drawn. The clip path is not shown in the right position.

[image: Clipped Image]

This is the generated svg XML

```
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1006" width="550" height="650" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs">
    <defs id="SvgjsDefs1007">
        <clipPath id="SvgjsClipPath1017">
            <rect id="SvgjsRect1014" width="315" height="600" x="120" y="27"></rect>
        </clipPath>
        <filter id="dilate_shape">
            <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceGraphic" radius="5" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="550" height="650" viewBox="0 0 550 650" xml:space="preserve">
        <g transform="translate(285 325)">
            <g filter="url(&quot;#dilate_shape&quot;)">
                <rect x="-325" y="-325" height="650" width="650" fill="lightgreen" clip-path="url(&quot;#SvgjsClipPath1017&quot;)"></rect>
            </g>
            <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/xOOB2O4.png" x="-325" y="-325" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="650" height="650" clip-path="url(&quot;#SvgjsClipPath1017&quot;)"></image>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

I can fix this if I remove the translate transform and add it's values into the x and y values of the child image tag. As shown in the following

[image: Fixed Clipped Image]

With the XML being

```
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1006" width="550" height="650" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs">
    <defs id="SvgjsDefs1007">
        <clipPath id="SvgjsClipPath1017">
            <rect id="SvgjsRect1014" width="315" height="600" x="120" y="27"></rect>
        </clipPath>
        <filter id="dilate_shape">
            <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceGraphic" radius="5" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="550" height="650" viewBox="0 0 550 650" xml:space="preserve">
        <g >
            <g filter="url(&quot;#dilate_shape&quot;)">
                <rect x="-40" y="0" height="650" width="650" fill="lightgreen" clip-path="url(&quot;#SvgjsClipPath1017&quot;)"></rect>
            </g>
            <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/xOOB2O4.png" x="-40" y="0" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="650" height="650" clip-path="url(&quot;#SvgjsClipPath1017&quot;)"></image>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

So how to I fix this without having to add the transform values into the X and Y positions. One thing to note is that I am using fabricJs(which is a canvas library to convert from canvas to an svg output). So the transforms are automatically applied when the conversion happens. Thus tinkering with the transform values afterwards effects additional images when conversion happens